# Full Width & Full Screen Videos wordpress with Divi Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

How can I put a video in the background in a full-width section on wordpress with Divi theme? when I put the video in the section setting that contain of fullwith section I missed some part of the video. my video size is 1920*1080 and I set the background video width to 1920 and height to 1080. I want the full size of the video to be displayed in this section.

my video size is 1920*1080 and I set the background video width to 1920 and height to 1080. I want the full size of the video to be displayed in this section.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Divi > Theme Options > General > scroll down to Custom CSS.
Add this:

```
.full-video-bg .et_pb_section_video_bg video {
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 100%!important;
        height: auto!important;
        min-height: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        position: relative;
    }
```